# Quick way to change importance of emails in inbox using Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 I want to manage emails I've **received**, by using the Importance flag.

I can open up an email and change the Importance flag under File, Properties.  (Which can be accessed by Alt, F, I, V and then Up or Down arrow and Enter.)

Is there a quicker way (eg a single keyboard shortcut, or somehow running a rule against a single email) to achieve this?

Thanks.  Please note:  This isn't about sending emails with high or low Importance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a quicker way: Quick Steps. Create a new custom Quick Step and choose "Set importance" action. Assign the shortcut as needed and save this Quick Step. That's all!

Comment: Perfect.  I've also added a keyboard shortcut to make it even easier.